# Can I disable a battery powered device by reversing half of its batteries?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, battery-operated, device

When I have a device that is powered by two batteries, can I disable it by turning one battery around?

For illustration, the purpose is to leave batteries in the device for storage, but it does not have an off switch. There are multiple solutions for this,  but I would like to understand specifically the solution using reversed batteries.

My idea is as follows: By turning around one of two 1.5 V cells, I let the + poles touch in the middle. The voltage between the - poles should now be 1.5 V - 1.5 V = 0 V. Therefore, there is no current through the device.

The problem is: Two batteries may not be perfectly balanced. One of them may be more discharged than the other, so they have different voltages.

It could work if the battery with more charge would be automatically discharged until it reaches the same level. Then, the cells would get into perfect balance, and stay that way even with fluctuations.

Does that make sense? What properties of the device are required?

If it works with two batteries, does it work too with other even numbers of battery cells?

Comment: Assuming these are non-rechargeable alkaline cells, I think you should just try it, then report back with the answer to your own question. It might work satisfactorily enough.

Comment: Four cells in series is really just two cells in series twice. So if it works for two cells, it will also work for four cells in series. But make sure you reverse exactly two cells. Otherwise you will end up charging the one cell with polarity opposite to all others. Many electronic devices have some form of reverse polarity protection. I used to design battery powered toys for kids. All of our products had either mechanical or electronic reverse polarity protection so that when any one battery was backwards, the current was zero. This was a hard requirement to ship the product.

Comment: it's usually easier tro use a piece of paper, card, or plastic as an insulating shim to break the circuit (just put the paper over the end of one of the battieries), when not in use it can probably be stored besidfe the battery

Comment: @Jasen I occasionally observe this with devices, which come with batteries included

Comment: If you can just disconnect the battery to flip it, why bother turning it around at all?

Comment: You are assuming the device just uses the two batteries in series. I've seen devices that don't work this way at all. For example, the remote for my cable box uses one battery to power its processor and IR transmitter and uses the other battery to produce a higher voltage just for its RF circuitry. (And yes, when it goes dead, swapping the batteries usually buys me another month or two.)

Comment: Why is it so important to store the batteries in the device?  Many people will tell you the reasons why doing so is a bad idea.  Why can't you store the batteries right next to the device, but outside it, to avoid damaging it?

Comment: To properly prepare an electronic device for long-term storage 1) take the batteries out of the device, 2) put the device into a plastic bag, 3) evacuate the air from the bag, and 4) seal it securely, 5) put the bag with the device inside it in a cool, dry place away from direct or indirect sunlight, 5) put the batteries in a separate plastic bag, 6) evacuate the air from the battery bag, 7) seal the battery bag securely, and 8) put that bag in the trash or the recycling bin, if you have one. 9) The next time you want to use the device remove it from its bag and install fresh batteries.

Comment: Similar question: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/43527/if-i-turn-a-aa-around-will-it-drain-or-damage-electronics

Comment: @MontyHarder becouse any living creature that doesn't know to not eat batteries, kids or larger dogs for example. I would just put a piece of plastic like they do when u buy it from a store in between one of the batteries. I can trust them not to leak (Energizer) when they say if they leak you get your money back. I also would not want to mix them with newer batteries by putting them back in storage with the rest.

Comment: @ldrrp do they also say if they leak you get back the money you spent on the device ruined by the leaked corrosive chemical stew?  If the batteries are small enough to be eaten by children and/or animals, you could use a locking drawer or cabinet door to keep them out.  What's to keep the kids from opening the battery door on the device and eating the batteries anyway?

Comment: @MontyHarder Most kids under a certain age are not capable of opening the back tray of a remote control. At least mine arent yet. Hell sometimes depending on the device i have a hard time. Eitherway as far as leaking batteries goes, i havent really had an energizer leak on me. the usual leakers are the battery that comes preinstalled from oem. Ive had the batteries go past expiration before ive had to replace them. my remote still has 2017 expired batteries and somehow still functions and no leaks yet. actually yea they will replace the device just googled. Alkaline batteries are the culrpits

Comment: @ldrrp My kids could open _anything_. I _never_ put those batteries that come from the OEM (in many cases in a shrink wrap, not actually installed in the remote) into the device.  I pull name-brand batteries out of my battery drawer for those.  I would recommend doing the same with a device you intend to store for a long time.  Take out whatever batteries you have, use them in something else, and get fresh batteries out when you remove the item from storage.

Answer (score 30):

If the batteries are not perfectly balanced they would still have some net voltage. And that is assuming that the batteries are connected in series.

If the batteries are connected in parallel, flipping one of them the other way around will basically create a dead short between them. At best, that is going to drain them.

In either case, storing batteries in a device is not a great idea. If the device ends up being stored for a longer period than you anticipated, and the batteries start leaking, the internals of the device is hardly an ideal place for them to spill their fluids.

Retrofitting an off switch would be better, although that still doesn't solve the issue of long time storage and leaking.

Comment: Yes, they would have a net voltage. But what happens because of that? The difference could get smaller by discharging one cell, until perfect balance.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel - No guarantee that they will balance after time.

Comment: Cells in series but reversed. So if current flowing is not zero, then one cell is charging and the other is discharging. So they WILL eventually balance. It is not good to charge alkaline cells, but in practice, if the voltages are very close, I do not think much charge current will flow. I think it will be OK as long as they are not far apart in voltage.

Comment: @mkeith That's the answer! It means that it will automatically stabilize to 0 V! Feel free to make it a short answer. The others contain lots of useful information that would apply if it were an X-Y-answer.

Comment: @VolkerSiegel Even if they zero out eventually, it doesn't remove the risk of a negative voltage in the beginning

Comment: +1 for retrofitting an on/off switch. We did this for our tractors, which due to some electrical faults tended to drain the battery over the course of days, when not in use for a long time. Solution A: find the fault, and fix it. Solution B: fit an on/off switch right at the battery.

Comment: Another thing: Primary cells don't work like you think they do. They really don't like to be charged (or recharged).

Comment: "At best, that is going to drain them." - you should probably mention the "at worst" too.  Damage by fire.

Answer (score 27):

You *can*, but as per @Dampmaskin's answer, it's not really the best plan.

Why not do as often seen in new electronic devices, and inserst a plastic slip between a battery and one of the terminals (or between two batteries).  If the slip is long enough to be seen outside the closed battery box, and a clearly visible sign says something like "remove before use", you can just pull the slip to "reactivate" the device.

You can also use posterboard or any other relatively rigid but thin non-conductive material to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: You can really use anything non-conductive here.  A thick piece of paperboard will also work, and is easy to cut into the appropriate shape.  I've used plastic poker chips in devices that take D-size batteries.

Comment: What you say is correct, but not answering the original question at all.

Comment: @Rev1.0 The [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) suggests that answering with a different solution from the one asked is OK: _"... Make sure your answer provides that – **or a viable alternative**. The answer can be “don’t do that”, but it should also include “try this instead”. Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful, but do try ..."_; This answer offers a different but definitely valid solution to the OPs underlying problem, so I feel this answer is perfectly acceptable and even helpful.

Comment: Indeed, people often ask an "X" question when they should be asking what's the best way to achieve "Y".  If I see such an XY situation on SE, I don't hesitate to call it out and address the Y instead of the X.

Comment: @marcelm: I get your point. Its just that he asked specifically about the implications of reversing a battery. Its not like he asked how to disable the device without removing the battery, that would be an entirely different story. And I do not see X/Y situation in this case. But maybe the downvote was a bit harsh ;)

Comment: @Rev1.0 Sure; but there are currently 4 other answers addressing to some degree the implications of reversing a battery. This answer provides a viable alternative that the OP (or any other reader) might not have considered, and might or might not prefer. I certainly don't think this answer should be the _only_ answer here, but in the current context it just expands the options of anyone reading this question, and I think that's a good thing! :)

Answer (score 13):

Very often, multiple batteries are series-connected. And the *total voltage* is used to power "stuff".
In that case, flipping a battery to turn off current works just fine.
However, the less-usual case of *parallel-connected* batteries won't allow you to flip one: the resulting failure could be spectacular.

It would be unusual, but possible that the series-connected mid-point between the two batteries is used for some purpose. This could be spotted by a wire emerging from the bridge that joins one battery "+" to the other battery "-". If the bridge is free of wires, you're good to go.
[image: Series-connected batteries, one flipped]

Keep in mind that battery-flipping as on-off mechanism involves a lot of battery-handling. Keep your fingers off those battery ends where electrical contact is made, and avoid touching the bridge or other electrical contacts. Finger grease/acids can increase contact resistance.
The other obvious caution is to **check which battery is flipped!**. You can easily apply reverse voltage to your electronics if you guess wrongly. After a few microseconds, you have likely trashed your device.

Comment: Flipping the battery in your photo is safe, because the battery case is designed to prevent electrical contact if the polarity is reversed (note the raised plastic around one end of the bridge).  In battery cases without this protection, flipping a battery can cause the other batteries to try to charge the flipped one, with potentially catastrophic results.

Answer (score 4):

You can. It is a bad idea for a few different reasons, besides those already listed.

1. You can yourself forget what you did. Depending on how important is the device, you may swear a lot. Or worse.
2. Batteries are geometrically asymmetric. Reversing one or more of them will change the length of the battery pack and/or face battery terminal to the wrong contact. You may have hard time inserting them in the battery compartment and/or deform the contacts, the compartment, the cap or something else.
3. Residual voltage - some (electronic) devices are especially vulnerable to very low voltages and may break in an unexpected manner.

Comment: I love the beginning: "You can. It is a bad idea...". Often people write "Don't do it" or "No, because it would create risk1, risk2,..." or "It would fail because..." instead. These are unclear.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, reversing one half of the batteries is likely to work... with some possibilities for trouble (leakage when the batteries expire and so on).

However that only works if your batteries are AAA, AA, C, D or similar cylindrical batteries with end connections... and only under circumstances where the container has open contacts. I've seen battery holders where polarity is 'enforced'... where the +ve end fits against an insulating plate with a hole or slot in it so when you turn the battery round no contact is made at the +ve connector (obviously the -ve end of the battery that is the wrong way round is sitting againstthe +ve end of the holder). The big -ve end of the battery won't fit into the hole or slot so the battery sits against the plastic insulator. That's obviously better than reversing because it's now an open circuit so it doesn't matter if the batteries don't have the same voltage... and you can break the circuit by turning only one battery round in a device with more than two batteries.

If your device uses button batteries, these are often connected to one end and to the side (or sides)... so turning round such a battery means you've got continuous metal between the +ve and -ve connectors of the holder... so the 'other' battery won't see the opposing voltage and the device will receive 1/2 of it's expected voltage. And one battery will run flat.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, reversing half of the batteries is likely to work.... for a while.  But it depends on what kind of batteries you have.   For example, Energizer batteries are guaranteed NOT to leak, whereas Duracell batteries are guaranteed to leak corrosive fluid into your device.   If you use Duracells, remove them when your device is in storage.